# MapBox Studio: Styling Water in template dataset

Tags: style, mapbox, zoom, visibility, water

I am using MapBox Studio with their own template dataset called `Outdoors`.
I discovered that categories of waterways can be addressed by classes such as `river`, `stream`, `stream_intermittent` etc. This allows me to toggle its visibility according to the zoom level. I want to do the same just for lakes and other water bodies. Unfortunately, the available layer "water" does not have such classes and presents just one layer containing all oceans, seas, and all other water bodies not considered rivers or such. Apparently, this accounts for their other datasets too.

This is confusing to me as smaller water bodies are not just scaled-down but disappear completely when you zoom out (see images) which means that there must be a way to access them by category.

I did not find an answer in the documentation so any help is welcome.

**Screenshot of two different zoom level views with different waterbodies**

[image: Screenshot of two different zoom level views with different waterbodies visible]